# Flutter App targeting Android 12 CRASHES => FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE to be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I develop App in Flutter. Would anyone suggest me where exactly I should change PendingIntent to use FLAG_IMMUTABLE? App installs on simulator but crashes at launching. Would anyone give a short example where to change it?

I read that workmanager 2.7.1 can help to solve the problem. Where exactly should it be added?

Comment: Consider accepting the answer by @SebastienB if it helped you. I'm just dropping this comment here so others who search for the error message find this thread. `Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.`.

Answer (score 14):

It worked for me simply by adding `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'` in the `dependencies` section of your `android/app/build.gradle`

It's the proposed solution of this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/93609

Comment: `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
    Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update D:\location\build.gradle:
    ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

Comment: i fixed the error by updating android/build.gradle from `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"` to `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"`

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue that my flutter app stop running into Android 12 devices and i m able to fix using below two changes:

1. I have added implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0' into android/app/build.gradle dependencies section.
2. I have added android:exported="true" into AndroidManifest.xml for all activity tag.